# How does Play Plugin know the Existence of Files before Compile-time

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

**How does the Play Plugin know whether or not an Assets file exists before compiling the code?**

I checked the `at` method in `AssetsBuilder` but do not see a clue.

[image]

I am trying to duplicate the functionality.  Please include some code or code locations.

My goal is to have the squiggly line if the file does not exist and allow for code refactoring if the filename were to change.

Comment: Play doesn't know that, actually. That will compile just fine. Are you using some sort of IDE plugin that maybe detects this?

Comment: @m-z I am using the Scala plugin for IntelliJ which provides support for Play.  Not sure if that is where such features would exist.

Comment: As @m-z said Play doesn't know it just generates the path to the resource _trusting_ that resource exists, in IntelliJ it's handled by Play 2 support plugin

Comment: @biesior I would like to know how this is done.  Changed my question to reflect its about the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What IntelliJ does is looking for the file inside the repository you've configured into your routes file.

By default a newly generated play app will have this route preconfigured:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Wich tells Play ( and IntelliJ pluging ) to look for your static assets into the public folder whenever you call `@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")`

**Edit**

If you want to access routes.Assets from a scala file you can `import controllers._`

Comment: But `routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")` only works inside the Twirl templates.  If I try to use it in a scala file, the package `routes` is not found.